# What's the best video compression library for Android?

Tags: android, library, video-recording

I'm still wondering what is, up to this date, the accepted video compression library for Android by community.

For example there are Android libraries that are widely used by the community and actively maintained like:

- [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/): for fields binding annotation.
- [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing): for barcode encoding/decoding
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) - [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/): for image downloading ad displaying

I'm not able to find such a library for video compression.

I see that some guys suggest [FFMPEG](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) but It's GPLv3 and I'd prefer one with MIT or Apache2 license.

Is this still the preferred choice to compress video before uploading them to a server like Instagram, Twitter, WhatsApp, Snapchat do or is there another better choice?

If I had to say the primary characteristic that it must have among others I would say that I'm searching for 'fastest' (shortest) compression time.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Example: are you after the best (highest) compression, or the fastest (shortest) processing time, or the best resulting quality …?

Comment: @Izzy Hi, thanks so much for your comment. I hope to have changed my answer as you suggest in your comment.

Comment: Definitely better, as now we have some more objective criteria. Not being an Android dev I cannot say if the details are sufficient (e.g. how much quality loss are you willing to accept for the compression being fast, and what is the minimal compression ratio that must be met? It certainly doesn't help much if it's "blazing fast" but has a compression ration of 5% at best, i.e. the remaining file size would be 95% of the original or more), so be welcome to clarify.

Comment: @shadowsheep it looks as though you didn't receive an answer to this. I don't suppose you have any information to share since posting the question?

Comment: @stustirling Hi! Nope! No answer... I’ve tested FFMPEG but no one gave me any suggestion

Comment: @StuStirling having tried only FFMPEG I've no suggestion too to share... :7